# MySQL UDF sys_exec() doesn't work

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I have a trigger which calls a stored procedure with parameters which calls `SET result = sys_exec(cmd);`. But it gives the error "function sys_exec does not exist".

I don't know what to do, on Tuesday I have presentation and because of this code line my project won't work.
The codes which I try to work.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE push_message
(p1   int,
 p2   int,
 p3 varchar(20))
BEGIN
 DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
 DECLARE result CHAR(255);
 SET cmd = CONCAT('curl https://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish/demo/demo/0/mysql_triggers/0/%22',p1, ',' ,p2, ',' ,p3,'%22');
 SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
END$$; 


CREATE TRIGGER push_message_trigger AFTER INSERT ON your_table_name_here
FOR EACH ROW
CALL push_message(NEW.id, NEW.num, NEW.name);
```

Comment: try execute or exec if you want to execute proc and see what it has to say.

Comment: Have you created functions, has run the file [lib_mysqludf_sys.sql](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys/blob/master/lib_mysqludf_sys.sql)?

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 5.5.35-1ubuntu1 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'plugin_dir';
+---------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                  |
+---------------+------------------------+
| plugin_dir    | /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ | -- copy 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so' here
+---------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS lib_mysqludf_sys_info;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sys_get;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sys_set;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sys_exec;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sys_eval;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION lib_mysqludf_sys_info RETURNS string SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION sys_get RETURNS string SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION sys_set RETURNS int SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec RETURNS int SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION sys_eval RETURNS string SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT sys_exec('curl http://stackoverflow.com/');
+--------------------------------------------+
| sys_exec('curl http://stackoverflow.com/') |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                          0 |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.12 sec)
```

For more details, visit: [24.3.2.5 Compiling and Installing User-Defined Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/udf-compiling.html).

Answer (score 4):

Try Once.

Steps to be followed:

- Get the files from https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys
- Go to the folder path in terminal.
- Execute:

  ```
  gcc -DMYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN -fPIC -Wall -m64 -I/usr/include/mysql -I. -shared lib_mysqludf_sys.c -o lib_mysqludf_sys.so
  ```

  NOTE: If 32-bit OS replace `-m64` with `-m32` in the above command.
- Execute the following in mysql shell:

  ```
  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'plugin_dir';
  ```

  This is an example of successful output:

  ```
  +---------------+------------------------+
  | Variable_name | Value                  |
  +---------------+------------------------+
  | plugin_dir    | /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ |
  +---------------+------------------------+
  ```
- Copy the `lib_mysqludf_sys.so` file to the above path.
- Execute the following in mysql shell

  ```
  CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec RETURNS INT SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';
  ```

Comment: SQL Error (1127): Can't find symbol 'sys_exec' in library

Answer (score 1):

sys_exec is not a MySql built-in function, you should use an User define function (UDF). Reference here [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-function-udf.html#:~:text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20function%20is,ABS()%20or%20CONCAT()%20.&text=function_name%20is%20the%20name%20that,of%20the%20function's%20return%20value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-function-udf.html#:%7E:text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20function%20is,ABS()%20or%20CONCAT()%20.&text=function_name%20is%20the%20name%20that,of%20the%20function%27s%20return%20value).

If your OS is Windows, use this (there are .so file for Linux and .dll file for Windows)
https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/tree/master/data/exploits/mysql

Download file and copy to your ../MySQL/lib or ../MySQL/lib/plugin directory.

Open MySQL, copy and execute this :

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS lib_mysqludf_sys_info;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sys_get;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sys_set;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sys_exec;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sys_eval;

CREATE FUNCTION lib_mysqludf_sys_info RETURNS string SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys_64.dll';
CREATE FUNCTION sys_get RETURNS string SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys_64.dll';
CREATE FUNCTION sys_set RETURNS int SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys_64.dll';
CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec RETURNS int SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys_64.dll';
CREATE FUNCTION sys_eval RETURNS string SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys_64.dll';
```

Then you can call an .exe file by :

```
DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
DECLARE result int(10);
SET cmd = "../<ProjectApp>/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/<appName>.exe";
SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
```