# How to connect mysql procedure to websocket?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, triggers

I was set lib_mysqludf_sys.dll library in;

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib\plugin

And I was created this mysql function;

```
CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec RETURNS int SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.dll';
```

It's created successful and not throw any exception.

Then I wrote this trigger on mysql;

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `bb`.`mytable_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `mytable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
Call new_procedure();
END
```

And procedure like this;

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN 
    DECLARE cmd CHAR(255); 
    DECLARE result CHAR(255); 
    SET result = sys_exec('curl http://localhost:9095/Laputa');
    INSERT INTO trggr VALUES(result);
END
```

But sys_exec function return 1 and not connect to url.

How can I connect any websocket from procedure.

My system:
 windows10 64bit, MySql Server 5.7 'version_compile_machine':'x86_64','version_compile_os':'Win64'

I wrote this by looking at them:

https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043795-can-i-publish-a-message-via-a-database-trigger-

[MySQL UDF sys_exec() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587333/mysql-udf-sys-exec-doesnt-work)

[Real time updates from database using JSF/Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947790/real-time-updates-from-database-using-jsf-java-ee)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`curl` is not a windows native command, you must download the binaries from [curl page](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win32) and copy the binaries (.exe and .dll) into your `c:\windows` directory... also you can use the full path of `curl.exe`

After that you can execute the command but `sys_exec` will return only 0 (success) or 1 (fail), to get the output of command you must use the `sys_eval` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sys_eval RETURNS int SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.dll';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @van Cachicatari. I was installed curl, I can call web service with command line(windows cmd) through `curl http://localhost:portNumber/api/.....`and return response correct it. But `sys_exec` and `sys_eval` not working.

Comment: when you open cmd.exe, do you able to run curl without problems?

Comment: Yes, I install curl on my system and define new system environment variables. Then I run it on cmd.

Comment: I just tried again with a fresh machine with MySQL 5.7 on Win7, it works fine for me :)   
Maybe you have another error that not permit run that command (firewall, permissions, etc)

Comment: Interesting:) Is win7 x64 or x86?

Comment: Win7 x86 Virtualbox machine....  and use a compiled version of that dll from: https://github.com/rootphantomer/hack_tools_for_me/tree/master/sqlmap%20lib_mysqludf_sys

Comment: @daylight did you get success with that?

Comment: No, I could not it. @Ivan Cachicatari