# MySQL Install the UDF library "mysqludf_sys" on a Windows Server 2016

Tags: mysql, windows, server, user-defined-functions

For 2 weeks I'm looking for a proper tutorial on how to fully install the library "lib_mysqludf_sys".

I got the .dll from a Russian site, because there seems to be no other for 64bit systems. I have successfully installed the procedure and also created the function, but whenever I want to call a file the whole database crashes. I conclude that the DLL file is faulty or that I forgot something to install.

can someone please explain to me how to use the UDF library to call files on a Windows Server 2016 64bit properly implied in the MySQL?

that would help me a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Download the Windows 64 bit version from here: 
https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/tree/master/data/exploits/mysql

Copy it to here or equivalent for your MySQL installation:
c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib\plugin\lib_mysqludf_sys_64.dll

Install and verify as per the instructions here:
https://osandamalith.com/2018/02/11/mysql-udf-exploitation/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using MySQL 57/earlier version. For the library, I suggest to control it with "dependency walker". See if there is any problem with dependency libraries. At lease KERNEL32.DLL and MSCVTR.DLL (Visual C++ Redistrubatable file) should be there without any warning on root level.

If you have the code, I suggest you to recompile it with mygwin64. There are many items needs to be fixed to compiled it. Following link is a good link for UDF DLL compiles

https://github.com/esabilbulbul/mysql-udf-windows

Answer (score 0):

There something similar, follow my answer here
[stackoverflow.com/a/65209718/10026099](http://stackoverflow.com/a/65209718/10026099)